# RabbitMQ start fail: Ranch listener permission denied

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to start my RabbitMQ broker server, but I encounter this error during starting process:

```
[error] <0.344.0> Failed to start Ranch listener ... for reason eacces (permission denied)
```

I used this server months before, but had no problem like this. Any idea what happend, how to solve it?
I tried RabbitMQ 3.6.12 and RabbitMQ 3.7.9, but none of them work. I have win10 OS.

Comment: How are you starting RabbitMQ? What version of Erlang? Are there any other interesting log messages? Is something else listening on the same port? You should check to see if `erl.exe` is already running.

Comment: I have checked your questions and the port 5672 was occupied by some other app. I have closed it and after start the RabbitMQ, the problem solved! Pleasa, add your comment as answer, and I will accept it. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something else listening on RabbitMQ's port? (`5672`) That is the most common reason for this error message.